# debug rails app inside docker with puma and vscode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging

I'm trying to run vscode debugger on a rails app.
The rails app runs inside a docker container, and it's run with puma config:

the docker-compose command:
`bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'`

puma.rb config

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup DefaultRackup
port ENV['PORT'] || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  worker_timeout 3600 # 1 hour to prevent debugger timeouts
end

before_fork do
  Barnes.start # Initializes runtime metrics
end
```

vscode config

```
{
      "type": "rdbg",
      "name": "Attach with rdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "debugPort": "localhost:12345",
    }
```

I tried many variations rdbg, debug, etc.

But can't get it to work yet

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure these things:

1. Configure docker to start your service with a debugger. Create a `scripts/entrypoint.sh` script in your app root:

```
#! /bin/bash
rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 \
           --port 1234 \
           --skip_wait_for_start  -- \
           bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3000'
```

i. In case `bundle` doesn't work, use the full path of binary, e.g.`/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle`
Read here for all available options in rdebug-ide: [rdebug-ide github](https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide/blob/master/bin/rdebug-ide#L46-L112)

ii. Make sure `ruby-debug-ide` and `debase` gems are installed inside container and on your machine.

2. In your docker compose:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: demo:latest
    working_dir: "/opt/app/demo"
    command: ["scripts/entrypoint.sh"]
    depends_on:     
      - redis
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
      - "1234:1234" # <-------- This is important, make sure to expose the debugger port
```

3. Create a `.vscode/launch.json` in your project Root directory:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to container",
            "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "/opt/app/demo", // <------ path inside container
            "showDebuggerOutput": true,
            "remotePort": "1234",  // <---------- port exposed in compose.yaml file
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

i.   If you are using Intellij, then put any random integer value in `dispatcherPort` param.

ii.  Ensure `Ruby` and `VS Code ruby debugger` extensions are installed in VScode

iii. If you use `rbenv` modify above extension options accordingly. `(Ctrl+Shift+P > Open user settings json)`

```json
    "rdbg.rubyVersionManager": "rbenv",
    "ruby.interpreter.commandPath": "/usr/local/home/atulvaibhav/.rbenv/shims/ruby",
```

This should be enough.
I faced some issues when using puma in clustered mode, so I modified `puma.rb` to run in single mode only by commenting out `workers` related setting in that file.

Now you should be all set. Bring up your containers: `compose up -d` > then go to VS-code and start the debugger named `Attach to container`